# What is the meaning of the Windows icon of a green axis attached to the fax machine?

Tags: windows-10, icons

I find a strange icon in Windows 10 shell32.dll. It looks like a green axis attached to the fax machine. I think it means a special fax machine, but I am not very sure what makes it special. I searched it on Google and MSDN, but I didn't find any answer.

So what does this icon really mean?

[image: The larger strange icon]

Comment: I don't think it means anything specific.

Comment: @Ramhound, but the regular fax machine icon doesn't have a green axis.

Comment: It's likely just an alternative icon.  Those icons have not changed in decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green-axis thing is used to indicate that the device is a network resource, not directly connected to the computer. There are also network folder, printer, etc icons with the same green axis.